# How to instruct predis to continue on error

Tags: php, redis, predis

In case of Redis failure, is that possible to instruct php predis (https://github.com/nrk/predis) to continue and to not die?

I have Redis to handle application cache, but the application can run without cache, it just hits the database heavier. I prefer to fallback to database then have the application dying. I cant find a way to instruct predis to continue on fail.

I thought in set the connection limit to about 5 seconds, if it cant connect to Redis the application should go on.

Is this possible?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Predis\Connection\ConnectionException: Operation timed out [tcp://128.0.0.1:6379]
```

Comment: Can't you just try-catch the redis part, and if the redis fail just continue to the regular code without caching?

Comment: simply use try-catch block

Answer (score 7):

You can catch the connection exception and fallback to your database.
Example:

```
try {
    return $predis->get('foobar');
} catch(\Predis\Connection\ConnectionException $ex) {
    // fallback to database call
}
```

For cleaner code wrap the database/redis call in a new class that abstracts away the actual connection, that way your calling code doesn't need to care which datasource was used.

Comment: Also, instead of `$predis->get('foobar');` you can do `$predis->ping();` which means you don't have to know any keys' names.